# rosjava on android emulator

Tags: rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello people!

Has anyone ever tried to run a rosjava app on an android emulator, with the ros-master on the host system (not on the emulator)?
I need such a configuration, but I don't know how to set it up.

greets

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/30018/rosjava-on-android-emulator/) by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on ROS Answers with karma: 77 on 2012-03-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I do not recommend using the Android emulator (performance is really bad). In theory, you could set things up using adb port forwarding: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/adb.html#forwardports

In practice, this isn't really possible since rosjava does not currently allow you to configure port ranges that should be used. Please file a feature request if that is something you need: http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list

---

Originally posted by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) with karma: 3838 on 2012-03-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [markkre](https://answers.ros.org/users/1624/markkre/) on 2012-03-28**:
Thank you for the hint! I already tried several emulator networking stuff on that website you posted. Now I know why nothing worked ;) Well, sometimes it would be handy having an emulator capable of ROS stuff ...

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi,

i'am working on the same problem. I want to connect the pub_sub_tutorial_app from android emulator to roscore on the same machine.
It seems that's not a problem to connect from emulator to roscore with the alias ip 10.0.2.2 because i can see the nodes in the nodelist.
But roscore can't find the emulator. Ok, that's similar to this post: http://answers.ros.org/question/10479/how-to-test-the-pub-sub-apps-with-avd/ (SebastianMuszynski).

However, when i use the clockwork tether app to get internet access on my computer everything works (almost) fine. So i can connect from emulator to roscore and back (i can see Hello World message and counter in the emulator).
But i don't understand why this works!!! At my point of view i think there is something with a tun interface and adb port forwarding (i can see some initialisations in the command window of the Tether program)...
The only problem is, that sometimes the tether app pops up in the emulator and nothing works so i want to reproduce this without the app..

Does anyone know why this works?
I wanna understand this but currently i can't...

@damonkohler: I don't understand why this isn't really possible! Please can you give me another chance to understand this?

Thanks!

---

Originally posted by [MR](https://answers.ros.org/users/14701/mr/) with karma: 11 on 2014-04-10

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1